# regular expression C#

Tags: c#, regex, url

i have html page with link like /with_us.php?page=digit and out.php?i=digit . how can i get all this links from page, but it will be better if i can collect immediately only digits from this links

Comment: I realize you're thinking along the lines of regular expression, but this is a little beyond the realm of context-free languages.  You might want to rewrite this question in terms of "scraping links from a web page using C#".  I imagine the Beautiful Soup library might be helpful here, but don't know if there are .NET bindings for it out there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) is ideal for this; this is almost the same as the example on the home page:

```
foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
{
    string href = link["href"].Value;
}
```

Now just parse "href"; perhaps something like:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(href, @"[&?]\w+=(\d+)");
int i;
if (match.Success && int.TryParse(match.Groups[1].Value, out i))
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Comment: amm, main question was than i need only link with such template /with_us.php?page=digit for example 
<a href=out.php?i=1456 target=_blank><b>go</a>
but your sample with HTML Agility Pack get ALL links from page. that i asked the question to find immediately only selected links

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try actually parsing the page and transversing the DOM.

Try:
http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack